# The inverse image of a cyclic tower

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The main goal is to show that if $G$ is finite, abelian, then $G$ admits a cyclic tower.

The proof I was given conducts an induction on the order of $G$. i.e., if $|G|=1$ then $G=<e>$ so it is a cyclic tower itself. Suppose for $|G|<n$, $G$ admits a cyclic tower. Let $e\not=x\in G$ and $G'=G/X$ where $X=<x>$. Then $|G'|=|G|/|X|<n$, so $G'$ admits a cyclic tower. Finally, by the cononical map $\pi:G\to G/X$, the inverse image of that cyclic tower is a cyclic tower in $G$.

What I'm confused about is that the cyclic tower we found in $G$ ends with $X$. Since I didn't use the fact $X=<x>$, I guess I have to make use of it, but don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

If the cyclic tower of $G'$ ends with trivial group $<X>$, then I'm done. But I guess not every cyclic group ends with the trivial group. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *preimage tower* to be cyclic, you just need the kernel of $\pi$ to be cyclic.   But $\operatorname {ker}\pi=X$.

Comment: Does it imply that the tower ends with the trivial group also? If so, how?

Comment: The last groups in the tower would be $X$, and then $\{e\}$ (unless of course $X$ is trivial).  Set $G_i=\pi^{-1}H_i$, where $H_i$ are the elements of the quotient tower.

Comment: But for $G_i$ to be $X$, shouldn't there be $H_i=X$ which is trivial in the quotient group?

Comment: If $X$ isn't trivial,  $G_m=\pi^{-1}(H_m)=\operatorname {ker}\pi=X$ is the second to last group in the preimage tower.  Where $H_m=\{e\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was wondering if $H_i=\{X\}$ exists.

Comment: Well $H_m=\{e\}$ exists, which,  as you noted, is $X$ in $G/X$.

Comment: What guarantees it??

Comment: The inductive hypothesis.   Use the definition of "cyclic tower".  It must terminate in the identity.  In the quotient that's the same as terminating in $X$.

Comment: Ok, now finally I get it. Thank you very much.